# TYPO3 Fluid combining with bootstrap datatables

Tags: datatables, typo3, fluid

I'm trying to combine fluid forms with bootstrap datatables. If I'm using this fluid form only everything works fine. I get the "selectedProdukts" argument in the calculate action.

```
<f:section name="main">

<f:flashMessages />
<f:form action="calculate">
<div class="container"> 

<table id="tbl_helios_products" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th><f:translate key="tx_heliostcotool_domain_model_produkt.bezeichnung" /></th>
        <th><f:translate key="tx_heliostcotool_domain_model_produkt.hersteller" /></th>
        <th><f:translate key="tx_heliostcotool_domain_model_produkt.warengruppe" /></th>
        <th><f:translate key="tx_heliostcotool_domain_model_produkt.preis" /></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <f:for each="{produkts}" as="produkt">
    <tr>            
        <td><f:form.checkbox name="selectedProdukts" property="selectedProdukts" value="{produkt.uid}" multiple="1"/></td>        
        <td>{produkt.bezeichnung}</td>
        <td>{produkt.hersteller}</td>
        <td>{produkt.warengruppe}</td>          
        <td>{produkt.preis}</td>
        <td>edit/delete</td>
    </tr>
    </f:for>
</tbody>
</table>

<f:form.submit value="Vergleichen" />

</div>
</f:form>
</f:section>
```

But if I add the javascript for activating the datatables the checkbox array argument is broken/incomplete. Then some activated checkboxes are correct and some are missing. If I order the table in another way, the array changes to other values but also not correct.

Here is the javascript for the datatables

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#tbl_helios_products').DataTable( {

 "order": [[ 1, "asc" ]],

 "columnDefs": [ {
        targets: [0,5],
        orderable: false
    }],

 "language": {
    "sEmptyTable":      "Keine Daten in der Tabelle vorhanden",
    "sInfo":            "_START_ bis _END_ von _TOTAL_ Einträgen",
    "sInfoEmpty":       "0 bis 0 von 0 Einträgen",
    "sInfoFiltered":    "(gefiltert von _MAX_ Einträgen)",
    "sInfoPostFix":     "",
    "sInfoThousands":   ".",
    "sLengthMenu":      "_MENU_ Einträge anzeigen",
    "sLoadingRecords":  "Wird geladen...",
    "sProcessing":      "Bitte warten...",
    "sSearch":          "Suchen",
    "sZeroRecords":     "Keine Einträge vorhanden.",
    "oPaginate": {
        "sFirst":       "Erste",
        "sPrevious":    "Zurück",
        "sNext":        "Nächste",
        "sLast":        "Letzte"
    },
    "oAria": {
        "sSortAscending":  ": aktivieren, um Spalte aufsteigend zu sortieren",
        "sSortDescending": ": aktivieren, um Spalte absteigend zu sortieren"
    }
 } 
});
});
```

Here is the result HTML from the fluid form:

```
<table id="tbl_helios_products" class="display dataTable no-footer" width="100%" cellspacing="0" role="grid" aria-describedby="tbl_helios_products_info" style="width: 100%;">
<thead>
  <tr role="row">
    <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 36px;" aria-label=""></th>
    <th class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tbl_helios_products" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 217px;" aria-sort="ascending" aria-label="Bezeichnung: aktivieren, um Spalte absteigend zu sortieren">Bezeichnung</th>
    <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tbl_helios_products" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 177px;" aria-label="Hersteller: aktivieren, um Spalte aufsteigend zu sortieren">Hersteller</th>
    <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tbl_helios_products" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 238px;" aria-label="Warengruppe: aktivieren, um Spalte aufsteigend zu sortieren">Warengruppe</th>
    <th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tbl_helios_products" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 108px;" aria-label="Preis: aktivieren, um Spalte aufsteigend zu sortieren">Preis</th>
    <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 151px;" aria-label=""></th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr class="odd" role="row">
    <td>
    <td class="sorting_1">Cleany</td>
    <td>Samsung</td>
    <td>Waschmaschinen</td>
    <td>4000</td>
    <td>edit/delete</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Any ideas? Datatables alone are working, Fluid alone is working, but combining them follows to strange results...

Comment: the usual problems with bootstrap is the timing of the javascript. either the HTML-DOM is not ready yet, or a lib is not loaded yet, also another JS can stop execution of your JS as it fails before your JS is executed. 
Second: check if the server-output (not the DOM the browser builds) is the same as expected.
The third possibillity is another JS which modifies your table before the DataTable-JS starts and where the resulting table can not be handled by the DataTable-JS.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem was the sorting oder searching. If I didn't sort the table in any way, then it also works.
But when I click a table header to sort the data and then send the form there were the wrong data in the result. I think this is because datatables manipulate the DOM but I'm not sure.

My solution now: I didn't use the flexform data of the checkboxes anymore. I created a small javascript which puts every ID of the selected dara in a hidden form field of the fluid form. This was send to the controller and I can work with that.

It's more a workaround than a solution but I'm satisfied with that ;)